# Properties of a Quotient Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we let $R$ represent a ring, and $I$ be an ideal of $R$, then we can define $R/I = \{I + a\mid a \in R\}$.

My question is what property of quotient rings allows us to state that if $I + a = I + b$, then $a-b\in I$?

Comment: That is not a property of the quotient ring, that it a property of addition.

Answer (score 2):

Say $a + I = b + I$. Since $0\in I$, $a + 0 = a\in b + I$, which means there exists $i\in I$ such that $a = b + i$. Now, this implies $a - b = i\in I$.